# How to get parameters in native iOS page passed from web view in Worklight?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

After passing parameters to native page, how do I fetch the same from the native page in iOS ?

Passing of parameters from web view

```
    var params = {
        width : "100",
        height : "100",
        logFileName: "dataPointLog",
        signatureImageName: "userSignature"
    };

    if (!nativeSignatureDrawClassName){
        alert(Messages.sign_err_msg);
    } else {
        WL.NativePage.show(nativeSignatureDrawClassName, CONFIGURATION.receivedSignature, params);
    }
```

Now, in the View controller ? How can I get the same such as "signatureImageName" in the above example?

I was thinking of something like this below, but it does not work.

```
@implementation SignatureViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"SignatureViewController" bundle:nil];
        if (self) {

            WLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (WLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            NSString *signaturePath = [appDelegate valueForKey:@"signatureImageName"];
            NSLog(@"Param value-> %@", signaturePath);
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Unfortunately, Worklight does not have anything in it's docs regarding this.

Comment: Did you try the nativepages example for iOS? There, parameters are passed; additionally if you are using 6.2, you can use the new actionsender functionality.

Comment: @IdanAdar Thank you. I had somehow missed it in the sample, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)setDataFromWebView:(NSDictionary*)data{
    paramName = (NSString*)[data valueForKey:@"paramName"];
    NSLog(@"%@",paramName);
}
```